# Sql syntax error coming up for only one product in the whole website

Tags: magento-1.9, product, database, error

I am getting the following error in my magento store when I try to access one particular product.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `catalog_category_flat_store_1` AS `main_table` WHERE (())

Every other product is working fine in my magento store. When I try to open the product page of one particular product I am getting the above magento error. Can anyone kindly tell me how to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

- Enable Magento log from **`System -> Configuration -> Advanced (Developer) -> Log Settings`**.
- Ensure that there is nothing in **`<Magento_Root>/var/log`** folder. Reload the product page for which you are getting the error.
- Now check for the logs in **`<Magento_Root>/var/log`** folder.

Hopefully, you would get some clue from here.